# What is the distinction between thermal and electrical conductivities?

Tags: electricity, thermal-conductivity

Aren't they both caused by electron motion?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2245/

Answer (score 5):

Thermal conductivity relates to the propagation of heat, whereas electrical conductivity relates to the *effective* propagation of electric charge.

In the case of thermal conductivity, not only the electrons play a role in the conduction but also phonons or magnons contribute to it. The electrons only play a significant role in heat conductivity in metallic materials, where you have relatively free electrons available.

Answer (score 1):

And that is why in general materials with high electrical conductivity also have high thermal conductivity. In fact for metals the two conductivities are related by the Wiedemann-Franz Law which says

\begin{equation} \frac{k}{\sigma}=LT \end{equation}

More details can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiedemann%E2%80%93Franz_law)